# Remote s3 Pdf file not opening in webview.

Tags: iphone

Pdf file Uploaded to amazon s3 bucket is not visible when open on UIWebView. When tried to open it on Browser the file gets downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

While uploading the pdf file on S3 bucket, specify the file type to PDF. And then the resulting url will open the pdf on both browser and UIWebView